# How do I change what filetypes Ubuntu One Ignores on a Mac (OSX)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mac, macosx

I understand how to add files to the syncdaemon.conf file in my Ubuntu system going to `/etc/xdg/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` and adding python strings to the `ignore.default` list.  It worked great.  I use ubuntu one on my mac OS X 10.8 and it sync's great, but I dont know where to update the `syncdaemon.conf` in order to make skip the same files as I did on my Ubuntu machine.  In the `Ubuntu\ One.app` there exist about 15 different `syncdaemon.conf` files.  Which one do I change?  Is it that simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out all you need to edit is the `~\Library\Preferences\ubuntuone\syncdaemon.conf`.  This file can be edited just the same as described in Linux.